# Form_for submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, say Model A and Model B, each one having certain fields (a1,a2,a3) and (b1,b2,b3).
I ran the scaffold command to generate the controllers and views for the models.
Now,
What i want to do is: -

> On the new page of model A, I want to add a button/ href lin to create a new B object.
>   When the user clicks the button, a div appears below which has a form for creating B object.
>   When the user clicks the submit button after filling in the details for model B object, the changes are saved to the DB directly.

NOTE : A and B are not related to each other.
Can someone suggest me a way to do so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the screencasts listed below from the incomparable [Railscasts series](http://railscasts.com/) if you haven't already watched then. They pretty much cover all the basics of processing multiple models on a singe form

- [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

To display a `<div>`'s contents when a button/link is clicked can be easily done in Javascript with JQuery (for example). That is described in the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).